# Cant get modal transition working on leave

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When im opening the modal, it transition without problems, but when hiding the modal, it doesnt transition out again - It just disappears.

I have the  inside the modal (Worked in Vue2), but that seems to be a problem... If I move the  component outside to the parent component and wrap the  component in the transition it works, but it seems like it's not possible to have the  component inside the component? Any ideas ?

See a Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cookies-rdm3w?file=/src/components/Modal.vue

Answer (score 0):

Move the transition tag into the parent, wrapping the component. If you wrap the transition on the modal / child component itself, the component will be unmounted when you click the close modal button, and the animation won't have time to run.

```
  <transition name="modal" :appear="true">
    <Modal v-if="showModal" @close-modal="showModal = false" />
  </transition>
```

Comment: I know that works, but in Vue2 in was possible to have the transition component inside the modal - So that's the point of it all... Is it even possible - I find it rather annoying that it forces me to always remember to wrap it in a transition component, instead of just defining it inside the component...